# How can I click the button next to a particular element in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write Selenium tests for HTML that's structured like this:

```
<table>
  <tr id="row-1">
    <td><span class="some_data">what I'm looking for</span></td>
    <td><button class="doSomething" onclick="..."></button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-n">
    <td><span class="some_data">not what I'm looking for</span></td>
    <td><button class="doSomething" onclick="..."></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need the test to click the button that's in the same row as `what I'm looking for`. I can find the `span` that it's in (`driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text() = "what I'm looking for"]')`), but I don't know how to get from there to the corresponding button.

I'm using the [Selenium Python bindings](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), version 2.21.2.

Comment: If your rows have ids, those should be unique.  Can you know or easily determine outside of the page what row id your desired button will be?  If so, just start there and build an xpath to td[2].

Comment: I wish :-) No, I'm afraid that all I know is the text in the `some_data` span.

Comment: Have you tried to work with parent and following-sibling http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
//tr[td/span[text() = "what I'm looking for"]]/td/button
```

If finds the `tr` which has a `td/span` with the text "what I'm looking for", then moves from that `tr` to the `td/button` inside it.